# How to make a javascript function visible internal to another and externally

Tags: javascript

I'm obviously not understanding the semantics of Javascript here (as I do with other, more, *um*, traditional languages).  Any guidance would be appreciated.

In a nutshell, `func2()` must be callable internally to `main()` as well as externally (with, eg, `main().func2()`):

First sample:

```
var main = function () {
    
    var func1 = function () {
        console.log('in func1()');
        // *** does not work
        func2();
    };

    return {
        // externally visible (eg, from other() below)
        func2: function () {
            console.log('in func2()');
        },    
        init: function () {
            func1();      
        }
    };
};

var other = function () {
    main().init();
    main().func2(); // *** works
}
```

Results in:

```
other();
VM1070:5 in func1()
VM1070:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: func2 is not defined
    at func1 (<anonymous>:7:9)
    at Object.init (<anonymous>:16:13)
    at other (<anonymous>:22:12)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Second sample:

```
var main = function () {
    
    var func1 = function () {
        console.log('in func1()');
        // *** works
        func2();
    };

    var func2 = function () {
        console.log('in func2()');
    }; 

    return {
        init: function () {
            func1();    
            func2();
        }
    };
};

var other = function () {
    main().init();
    main().func2(); // *** does not work
}
```

Results in:

```
other()
VM1097:5 in func1()
VM1097:11 in func2()
VM1097:11 in func2()
VM1097:24 Uncaught TypeError: main(...).func2 is not a function
    at other (<anonymous>:24:12)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
other @ VM1097:24
(anonymous) @ VM1117:1
```

How can I define `func2()` in `main()` such that it can be called from anywhere?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you might find ES6 classes more interesting for that logic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Declaring a variable or function in another function does not make it part of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to make `func1` and `func2` properties of the object you return. As it is, they're just local symbols in the `main()` function.

```
var main = function () {
    
    var func1 = function () {
        console.log('in func1()');
        // *** works
        func2();
    };

    var func2 = function () {
        console.log('in func2()');
    }; 

    return {
        init: function () {
            func1();    
            func2();
        },
        func1: func1,
        func2: func2
    };
};
```